# появление блока через animate.css

Tags: jquery, css-animation

Есть спрятанный блок, который вылазит(или должен) по клику на кнопку. Ему же добавляется для анимации в класс `animated %названиеАнимации%`. Но если он `display:none` то как сделать что бы меню вылазило с указанной анимацией

```
$('#nb-close-toggle').click(function(){ //кнопка
    $(this).toggleClass('open'); 
    var animationName = "какая то анимация";
    $('.menu').addClass('animated ' + animationName).one(animationEnd, function() {
            $(.menu).removeClass('animated ' + animationName);
        });
    });
```

Comment: попробуй перед .addClass добавить .show()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как-то так

```
$('.menu').show(0).addClass('animated ' + animationName).one(animationEnd, function() {
  $(.menu).removeClass('animated ' + animationName);
});
```